# Asking to take photos in Russian

Tags: местоимения

If I want to say "can I take a photo of you (your face)", how should I proceed?

Могу снять фото на вас?

Могу снять портрет ваш?

Or neither of the aforementioned?

Comment: Both phrases are incorrect - I'm mentioning this only for a future references

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's *можно вас сфотографировать?*

*Фотографировать* is Russian for "photographing", "taking a picture", and it has a direct object in accusative, so there is not need to recourse to analytic constructs similar to English ones.

As a side note, Russians are usually not particularly fond of people on street taking their pictures without a good reason, so if you just want to take a photo of a stranger on the street, it would not hurt to throw in some kind of explanation:

> *Простите, можно вас сфотографировать? Я из …, мне для …*
>
> "Excuse me, can I take your picture? I'm from …, and it's for …".

Comment: Better yet, use the form: "... разрешите Вас сфотографировать ..." offering an apology and an explanation, like @Quassnoi said.

Comment: As a side note—I've never heard a Russian use the word (с)фотографировать. They all seems to use (с)фоткать/ (с)фоткаться.

Comment: @VCH250 LOL. I wonder (actually no, I want never know that) who are people with who you are usually contact.

Comment: What a coincidence! When I was in Russia last year, I told a few people "можно сфотографировать вас?" precisely! I just wanted to know if there's an alternative way to tell it, but apparently not.

Answer (score 3):

If one is asking complete strangers I'd go with `Вы не против, если я вас сфотографирую?` - it sounds to me subtly more polite and sort of less insistent rather than `можно`-form mentioned in the different question (which is 100% percent valid of course).

Answer (score -2):

в разговорной речи так ( in colloquial speech so ) :

не правильно (not properly) :
простите разрешите..

правильно:
можно вас сфоткать?
можно с вами сфоткаться?

Comment: Too many mistakes (almost in every word) for a person pretending to be a teacher...