# How can I ask someone to take a photograph of me?

Tags: одним-словом

Something like 'Could you please take a photo of me? . I searched everywhere and can't seem to find something similar.

Comment: Interesting enough that in real life situations people usually DON'T even use the word ("снимите", "сфотографируйте" etc.) Saying "Пожалуйста" or "Можно вас попросить" while handing over a smartphone or camera is sufficient. A complete, language-correct request is a rarity.

Comment: Linked: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16844/asking-to-take-photos-in-russian/16845

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«Сфотографируйте меня, пожалуйста.» or «Сфотографируете меня, пожалуйста?» is something I’d probably say.

Answer (score 6):

**сфотографируйте меня пожалуйста** is not exactly an equivalent of your English phrasing, because it sounds somewhat presumptuous as if you were already sure the person would agree and it makes it harder for them to refuse.

А more accurate translation and also a more polite (in my view) address would be

> Вы не могли бы меня сфотографировать?
>
> OR
>
> Можно вас попросить меня сфотографировать?
>
> OR
>
> Нельзя ли вас попросить меня сфотографировать?
>
> OR a little less formal
>
> Вы меня не сфотографируете?

Here you basically ask whether the person would agree to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the age of mechanical cameras, their mechanical triggers used to give out a specific sound, "щелчок". Accordingly, in the conversational speech, it was normal to ask "щёлкни нас на память".

The people older than forty will easily understand the verb "щёлкнуть" as a conversational synonym to "сфотографировать". A much younger person should be well-read to understand this.

À propos, from a poem by Akhmadullina (about Akhmatova):

И тень её грядущей муки
Защёлкнута ловушкой снимка.